# Is there any valid reason why gem omniauth-rails_csrf_protection in only Rails 4.2+ compatible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, csrf, omniauth

I was wondering is there any valid reason why [omniauth-rails_csrf_protection](https://github.com/cookpad/omniauth-rails_csrf_protection) is not compatible with the versions of Rails below 4.2? Are there some functionalities in Rails 4.2+ that are crucial for this gem to work, and hence can't be used with lower versions of Rails?

I would like to use [omniauth-rails_csrf_protection](https://github.com/cookpad/omniauth-rails_csrf_protection) with Rails 4.0 app. But it is not compatible.

Comment: Rails 4.2 is end of life. If you choose not to update to a supported Rails version then you do so at your own risk. Rails 7 has [CSRF countermeasures](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures) built in.

Comment: Thx for the reply :), yeah I know that it's EOL, I was just wondering if there were any code/technical limitations in Rails 4.0 that were fixed in Rails 4.2, and hence this gem is not compatible with Rails 4.0 :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. So, it's the code from [actionpack 4.2.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb) that is used to make the `omniauth-rails_csrf_protection` gem work. In the [token_verifier.rb](https://github.com/cookpad/omniauth-rails_csrf_protection/blob/v0.1.2/lib/omniauth/rails_csrf_protection/token_verifier.rb) a method `verified_request?` is called which is implemented in actionpack. But it was modified in actionpack 4.2.0, hence `omniauth-rails_csrf_protection` gem won't work with Rails version below 4.2.0.